# How to rotate the image and in the end change the image using Animation

Tags: android, android-animation

As the title says I am trying to perform an animation effect on the `imageview` where on click of `Button` the image starts rotating and in the end of the `animation effect` the image changes to another `image`

Comment: What you have achieved so far. post some code of that...

Comment: @ Rajeev Arora .... Ive written just `onclick` of button as basic backbone but not. trying to learn animation of this type... any head-up on any resources to go to ?

Comment: "change the image using animation", what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Blaze Tama ... **Ex:** `image1.jpg` to `image2.jpg`

Comment: @Devrath no, i mean you want to change with animation? Or playing animation and change the image at the end of animation?

Comment: @Blaze Tama .... playing animation and change the image at the end of animation? **Ex** : Human body facing front image starts rotating(playing animation) in the end shows human body facing back

Answer (score 2):

Animation rotation.xml in res/anim something like this (play around with parameters for your particular rotation flavour):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate android:duration="300"
            android:startOffset="0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="360"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            ></rotate>
    </set>
```

In activity something like this:

```
Button yourButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);

                   yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                           Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(yourActivity, R.anim.rotation);

                           animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                   v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anotherImage);
                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                               }
                           });

                           v.startAnimation(animation); 
                       }
                   });
```

Edit: unless by rotation you mean "flip"? Perhaps also check this out: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured out if you want to change the image after it rotates with animation it is a kind of one way i.e you cant revert back to old image on 2nd click or more. So only way to do that was perform the same animation on Checkbox instead of Imageview/button.

### Below is my code:-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
   android:id="@+id/ivCLick"
   android:layout_width="40dp"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:layout_margin="40dp"
   android:background="@drawable/chbselector"
   android:button="@null"
   />
```

chbselector.xml :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_grey_24dp"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_grey_24dp"/>
</selector>
```

rotation.xml:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:duration="300"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:fromDegrees="0" />
</set>
```

My Java Code:-

```
 findViewById(R.id.ivCLick).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rotation);

            animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onAnimationEnd: "+((AppCompatCheckBox)v).isChecked());
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            v.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    });
```

((AppCompatCheckBox)v).isChecked() gives you weather you clicked on the image or not.Can do whatever with it as you desire.